# EditText input type not changing

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am showing a dialog with edit text and set the input type decimal like this

```
**final EditText input = new EditText(context);

input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);**
```

It's input type working fine if I am using default **alert.setPositiveButton**  and **setNegativeButton** click listeners. But when I used the

**dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { }**

then it's input not working.
Below is my code complete code

```
package com.Dialogs;


public class GetSalesTaxPopUp {
    Context context;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    public void getSalesTax(Context context2){
        this.context = context2;
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alert.setTitle("Sales Tax");
        alert.setMessage("Enter Tax");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText input = new EditText(context);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            }
        });
        dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String salestax = input.getText().toString();
                if(!salestax.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(context, salestax, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Enter Sales Tax", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!MyPreferences.getMyPreference("GetSalesTax", context).equals("")){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Enter Sales Tax First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    //  alert.show();
    }
}
```

Please guide me where I am doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need both the input type class and the decimal flag:

```
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `dialog.show();` at the very last.

Other than that, i would suggest you to use:

`alert.setPositiveButton` instead of `dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)`

Comment: dialog.show(); didn't worked. If I used the alert.setPositiveButton  then I can't set the conditions onClick of the positive and negative buttons like currently I am doing.

Comment: we can't set the input type in that case ?

Comment: when using setPositiveButton then you need to provide `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

Comment: `getButton().setOnClickListener()` method is needed if you want to do any validation before the dialog is dismissed - `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` fires only after dismiss. And `getButton()` returns null until the dialog is showing so moving the `show()` to the end would lead to NPE.